# Nested Case Expressions In SELECT

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having some difficulty pulling conditional data in a SELECT statement using conditionals.

There's the outer condition checking if a value isn't null and an inner condition checking if the value contains a particular set of characters.

The select statement:

```
       refID = CASE externalID
       WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN CASE internalType
           WHEN CONTAINS(internalType,'B1') THEN 'C1' + externalID
           WHEN CONTAINS(internalType,'B2') THEN 'C2' + externalID
           ELSE 'Ext'
           END
       ELSE 'N/A'
       END
```

Unfortunately, running this code ends with the error message "*incorrect syntax near IS*"

Comment: Case expression, not statement.

Comment: case when externalID IS NOT NULL THEN ...

Comment: Thanks, but that has just pushed the error forward to "Incorrect syntax near CONTAINS"

Comment: Do the similar switch.

Comment: Do you mean LIKE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the field into the case

```
   refID = CASE 
                WHEN externalID IS NOT NULL THEN 
                     CASE 
                          WHEN internalType like '%B1%' THEN 'C1' + externalID
                          WHEN internalType like '%B2%' THEN 'C2' + externalID
                          ELSE 'Ext'
                     END
                ELSE 'N/A'
           END
```

Comment: @W.H I should have left that one there, methinks

Comment: Thanks, that has fixed it. Unfortunately CONTAINS cannot be used as the table is not indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Hi
 In this case you can use **INSTR** function,

```
refID = CASE externalID
   WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN CASE internalType
       WHEN INSTR(internalType,'B1') THEN 'C1' + externalID
       WHEN INSTR(internalType,'B2') THEN 'C2' + externalID
       ELSE 'Ext'
       END
   ELSE 'N/A'
   END
```

INSTR - instring function checks the required string or pattern and processes the data

Comment: You need to use INSTR function for accurate pattern check

Comment: Thanks, that's great! Works fine.

Comment: My pleasure to help you